# Extending Apache charm to include Apache Modules

Tags: apache2, juju

I want to deploy apache with modules such as mapcache and mapserver.  Can the apache charm be reused as a library?  The apache charm is non-trivial so I don't want to copy the apache charm module and extend it since I would then be responsible for maintaining any updates to the standard apache charm.

I would like to do something in the install file like this:
juju-include apache2

Is there anything like this?  If not, what is the best way of proceeding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including additional Apache modules is a great idea and seems like it could be very helpful in the core charm itself. What I'd recommend doing is implementing this via the [`config.yaml` & `hooks/config-changed`](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/service-config.html) so you could not only change what *additional* modules were installed but also add/remove modules on the fly. Then I would open a merge request against the current charm to have it included by default. Charms are pretty extensible and often time if you find a general need a charm doesn't fullfil, you won't be the only one.

So if you do make a change to a charm (and don't wish to maintain a fork) consider submitting it to be merged in to the Charm Store version of the charm by uploading the branch to `lp:~<your-launchpad-username>/charms/<series>/<charm>/<branch_name>`. Most of the time series will be the LTS name (precise, for example), charm would be "apache2", and the branch name can be anything, most people choose "trunk". Someone from the [~charmers](https://launchpad.net/~charmers) team will review and provide feedback on your changes and, if it passes inspection, will just be merged to be part of the actual charm itself!